# MediaCodec has an error about OMX.ST.VFM.H264Enc on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, yuv

I want to **encode YUV data to H.264** video using mimeType of `video/avc`.But the instance of MediaCodec can't be created because there is no suitable color format.

The cellphone that I use is **Samsung GT-I8160 with Android 4.1.2(API 16)**.

I get the encoder named `'OMX.ST.VFM.H264Enc'` through mimetype "video/avc",and get three supported color format namely `2147483646`, `2141192192`, `2130708361`.

I find `2130708361` equals to `COLOR_FormatSurface` in Android API. But I can't find `2147483646`, `2141192192` in Android API. So, what's the meaning of `2147483646` and `2141192192`?

If I can't find correct color format I can't encode YUV to H.264 stream. How to get the color format about YUV on Samsung GT-I8160 with Android 4.1.2 (API 16)?

Or, what is the meaning of color format `2147483646` and `2141192192` and how to use them?

Comment: Seems like the color that you found are vendor specific formats. Also, the device has an API level that does not require to pass CTS tests = no guaranty

Comment: @E.Abdel Thank you.But what should I do? Do I  give up the device?